# Buttons under the action bar

Tags: android

First of all, I have no idea how it's called but it looks like this:

[image]

See those words: **ALLE KREISE** , **IN DER NAHE...**  <- second, this is what I want to add in my app.
So, 3 different buttons (example: Europe / China / USA ) and when I press each of them I want a webpage to show up.

Comment: Do you want the webpage to open within the app, or externally (such as in Google Chrome)? If it is the latter, that it not really the intended use of these `ActionBar Tabs`. They are mainly used for navigation within the app.

Comment: Yes, I want the webpage to open within the app.

Comment: It's a TabBar. http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Comment: Thanks guys. Does any of you know a good tutorial on how to implement a TabBar ?

Comment: @MasterZYuri http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/06/android-action-bar-with-tab.html